# Optional parameters for type parameters?

Tags: typescript

I have the following defined in my application:

```
export interface ICallback<TReturnType> {
    (): TReturnType;
}

export interface ICallbackWithParam<TReturnType, TParamType> {
    (param: TParamType): TReturnType;
}

export interface ICallbackWithTwoParams<TReturnType, TParamOneType, TParamTwoType> {
    (paramOne: TParamOneType, paramTwo: TParamTwoType): TReturnType;
}
```

The naming feels off here.  Really these are all `ICallback` interfaces to me.  Having to name them by number of parameters seems.. off.

I can keep using them this way, adding a new one whenever I need more parameters in a callback.  But I thought I would ask if there is a better way in TypeScript.

Optional type parameters is one way, but my initial research shows they are not supported.

**Is there some other way to not have to build expanding, semi redundant exports like above?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of code generation, not at the moment. TypeScript does not have support for variadic generics, although this has been [brought up before](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1773).